# Is it good practice to re-sign all packages from a mirror for extra security?

Tags: gnupg, apt-mirror

If I were to mirror ubuntu zesty repo, should I re-sign all deb packages with my server's gpg signing key (that the users on my website would be able to download)? Or should I jsut leave the packages as-is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* resign the packages. Not only is there no need to do so, but doing so would actually do harm unless all clients are managed systems trusting your mirror's key.

The apt package manager verifies signed packages against a list of keys shipped by the distribution's vendor (ie., Ubuntu). It does not care where the packages come from, as long as they're properly signed: if the signature is valid, the package was not tampered with after being issued by the key owner. You can trust the package, even if it was transmitted through dubious channels! *Any* mirror (including peer to peer distribution and in fact, even the upstream repository servers) can be considered as untrusted sources with respect to package signature validation, still the package source can be validated.

By swapping the signatures with such of your own key, the signatures cannot be validated against the built-in keyring, but this must be extended by your own key. This might be reasonable for a closed user base (eg., all company clients), but definitely not for open mirrors providing services for an unmanaged userbase. Those would fail at validating signatures unless they install the key (and thus trust your mirror) manually.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to re-sign packages, as you know the packages are already signed:

> Apt-get package management uses public key cryptography to authenticate downloaded packages.

Read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt) and [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt).

If something has been compromised with, `apt` will figure it out it self.